# Kendo Grid Page Persistence

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

This is a more conceptual question, so I'm not initially submitting any code for it unless someone requests it.

On a current website of mine, I am using a Kendo UI grid to display a table of multiple pages. I also have a (Kendo UI) drop down list, allowing the user to filter rows by class (it reloads the page and makes the necessary edits through the controller).

My problem is this: when the user pages through the Kendo UI grid, it loads a new page and the filtering preferences do not persist. How can I make it either not reload the page(and do everything on the same page instead), or make the drop down box's value persist? Thanks, and tell me if there's any information that would be helpful for me to add!

CLARIFICATION: The functionality is all fine, the only issue is that the dropdownlist does not visually persist.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can bind both dropdownlist and grid to a single external datasource. This datasource will actually place a ajax call and get the records when the value in drop down changes. As the new records appear in datasource the grid can be refreshed or will automatically refresh without the page reload. Page reload doesn't look like a clean way to filter the grid.